# Consulta para pegar diferença de data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma consulta desse tipo no MongoDB com diferença de data e pegando o último registro em uma faixa de data.

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(),DATAHORA) AS DIAS FROM TBLTRANSFERS 
        WHERE IDTRANSFER IN (SELECT MAX(IDTRANSFER) 
                       FROM TBLTRANSFERS WHERE DATAHORA BETWEEN '2017-10-26 11:42:28' 
                       AND '2017-11-13 11:42:28' 
                       AND (EVENTO = 1 OR EVENTO = 3) 
                       AND RESULTADO = 0 GROUP BY USUARIO) 
ORDER BY USUARIO DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo de pegar dados entre um range de data seria:

Vamos supor que voce salva assim:

```
collection.save({
    name: "example",
    dataCriacao: "Sun May 30 18.49:00 +0000 2010"
})
```

Voce poderia consultar:

```
collection.find({"dataCriacao":{$gte:new ISODate("2017-11-20T23:59:59Z"),$lte:new ISODate("2017-11-21T11:46:59Z")}}).count().pretty();
```

Ou também:

```
collection.find({
    dataCriacao: {
        $gte:"Mon May 30 18:47:00 +0000 2015",
        $lt: "Sun May 30 20:40:36 +0000 2010"
    }
})
```

Verifique: As vezes é necessário converter para o formato de data que MongoDB suporta, por isso o exemplo `ISODate`.

Veja mais exemplos na documentação official do [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/#examples).